# C# OPC DA read values

Tags: c#, opc-da

im trying to read value from OPC over DA protocol. I have found that titanium-as is free, thats my condition. i'm using [this](https://github.com/titanium-as/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client) manual, where is writen how to read values from OPC server, but only from groups which you made on OPC server with your own created variables. I wanna read values which are already on OPC server and create group from them so i can read their values.

SOLVED

Here is solution

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();

        Uri url = UrlBuilder.Build("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6");

        using (var server = new OpcDaServer(url))
        {
            server.Connect();
            OpcDaGroup MyGroup = server.AddGroup("MyGroup");
            MyGroup.IsActive = true;
            var browser = new OpcDaBrowserAuto(server);
            OpcDaBrowseElement[] MySimulation = browser.GetElements("Simulation.Functions");
            OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = new OpcDaItemDefinition[MySimulation.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < MySimulation.Count(); i++)
            {
                definitions[i] = new OpcDaItemDefinition { ItemId = MySimulation[i].ItemId, IsActive = true };
            }
            MyGroup.AddItems(definitions);
            MyGroup.ValuesChanged += OnGroupValuesChanged;
            MyGroup.UpdateRate = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100); // ValuesChanged won't be triggered if zero           
        }
    }
    static void OnGroupValuesChanged(object sender, OpcDaItemValuesChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Output values.
        foreach (OpcDaItemValue value in args.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemId: {0}; Value: {1}; Quality: {2}; Timestamp: {3}",
                value.Item.ItemId, value.Value, value.Quality, value.Timestamp);
        }
    }
```

For forms you need to edit Program.cs like that

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    //[STAThread]
    
    static void Main()
    {
        TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();
        var thread = new Thread(RunApplication);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();  
    }
    static void RunApplication()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any advise.

Comment: So creating a group is the problem? [docs](https://github.com/titanium-as/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client#creating-a-group-with-items) . Seems like you are missing some stuff like `OpcDaGroup group = server.AddGroup("MyGroup");` and `group.IsActive = true;`?

Comment: Adding items to group is my problem, i cant figure how to read items from OPC and this items add to my group

Comment: Seeing your code, you have not even initialised your group using the `MyGroup = server.AddGroup("MyGroup")` code. What error do you get when running? Give more details about the problem.

Comment: Forgive me, i think that its not initialization, but adding new group to OPC server. Error  is on this line `definitions[i].ItemId = MySimulation[i].ItemId; ` it returns Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
in variable `MySimulation` i got 17 items, but i cant transfer them to `definitions`

Comment: So you want to retrieve the structure from the server and read those values? For that you will need to write some recursive methods for browsing the structure tree: this is some sample code: [link](https://github.com/titanium-as/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client#browsing-elements) . When you get the `element` you can probably get the `ItemId` from it and create a new `OpcDaItemDefinition` and add that to your group.

Comment: Many thanks for your time, i have figure it out, i will update code.

Comment: Okay, I see, gonna give some sample code to fix that issue

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is when you iterate your `definitions`collection you have not really added any items to it yet:

```
OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = new OpcDaItemDefinition[MySimulation.Count()];
for (int i = 0; i < MySimulation.Count(); i++)
{
      definitions[i] = new OpcDaItemDefinition(...);
      //definitions[i].ItemId = MySimulation[i].ItemId;
      //definitions[i].IsActive = true;
}
MyGroup.AddItems(definitions);
```

This should solve that error.

EDIT: just saw your edit, you solved it too.

Comment: Yes, this was a problem, sorry for my stupidity not seeing that. At least maybe this will help someone.

Comment: No problem, glad you found it.

Comment: i have found another problem ... what if i will try to move this solution to windows Forms app. i cant find place where to put `TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();`
i have tried to put in to `static void Main()`, but this giving me error `ExternalException: CoInitializeSecurity: Security must be initialized before any interfaces are marshalled or unmarshalled. It cannot be changed once initialized.`. Thank you again for any advice.

Comment: Looking at the source code for that method it has some more information on how to use it: [source file](https://github.com/titanium-as/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client/blob/master/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client/Bootstrap.cs).

Comment: Thanks, i have edited my question. hopefully i done it right way

Comment: I have never needed this library but if your problems are solved by these changes then you should be fine. I would suggest to make different questions for each problem next time ;).